# Why can't I style this label tag?

Tags: html, css

No matter what I do, the label tags will not be styled by my CSS.

CSS:

```
label {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
            <form action="post">
                <label for="name">Name:<input type="text" id="name" class="text" /></label>
                <label for="email">Email:<input type="text" id="email" class="text" /></label>
                <label for="message">Message:<textarea id="message"></textarea></label>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

Guess what? NOT LUCIDA GRANDE.

In action here: http://christianselig.com/contact.html

Comment: hard to say without seeing the rest of your css, as something may be overriding that labels style.

Comment: Assuming your talking site.css or something use firefox and firebug to find the css path and put that path in

Comment: I would start by inspecting the elements in developer tools in chrome or firefox, check that your stylesheet was included in the page, and then look at the styles that were applied to the element. In chrome or firefox with developer tools enabled, you just right click -> inspect element.

Comment: I've got all the linking of files working. The page is here: http://christianselig.com/contact.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xa9LJ/ Works for me.

Comment: In your css put this path in "html body div.contact-form form label"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps its because `reset.css` is overriding `style.css`?

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

The `label` selector is included on line 8 of this block in `reset.css`:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit; 
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch... I was too focused on the element to see the real issue.